# How to launch Ubuntu on an Acer GX-781?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, acer

I'm having difficulties launching Ubuntu from my PC (also dual boot with Windows 10). I have Ubuntu installed and the installation went through fine, but I can't seem to get Acer to understand how to allow Ubuntu.

If someone could be so kind and write me the steps I have to do in order to allow Ubuntu (or otherwise help me, e.g. link me to a video, tutorial etc.), it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A very comprehensive guide here. [how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi/228069#228069)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to "Hobbyist" for answering my question! [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi/228069#228069) helped quite a lot!